# Design pattern code for conditional code scattered across multiple classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

Some code needs to be refactored in approx 10 classes, of these
classes there are conditionals scattered throughout the classes painting
text onto the screen where appropriate. I want to add all this code conditional/painting
code into one centralised location. 
Is there a design pattern appropriate for this ?

```
if (fontWidth == 100) {
    fontSize = large;
} else {
    fontSize = small;
}

if (fontWidth == 100) {
    graphics.drawText("100", xVal, yVal);
} else {
    xText = Utils.calculateXText(param1, param2);
    graphics.drawText("200", xVal, yVal);
}
```

For delegation does it mean I need to write defferent wrapper objects, one for setting the font size and one for drawing the text based on above  code ?

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics){

    super.paint(graphics);
    Font font;


    if(ScreenDimension.getFontWidth() == 320){
        font = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,10,Ui.UNITS_pt);
    }
    else {
        font = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,12,Ui.UNITS_pt);
    }

String strScore = String.valueOf(score);
    graphics.setFont(font); 
    int pixelWidth = font.getAdvance(strScore);


    if(ScreenDimension.getFontWidth() == 320){
        graphics.drawText(strScore, (int) (this.backgroundBitmap.getWidth() * 0.50) - (pixelWidth/2), 10);
    }
    else {
        graphics.drawText(strScore, (int) (this.backgroundBitmap.getWidth() * 0.50) - (pixelWidth/2), 20);
    }

    if(ScreenDimension.getFontWidth() == 320){
        font = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,6,Ui.UNITS_pt);
    }
    else {
        font = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,8,Ui.UNITS_pt);
    }

    int namePixelWidth = font.getAdvance(judgeName);
    graphics.setFont(font);

if(ScreenDimension.getFontWidth() == 320){
    graphics.drawText(judgeName, (int) (this.backgroundBitmap.getWidth() * 0.50) - (namePixelWidth/2), this.backgroundBitmap.getHeight() - font.getHeight() - 2);
}
    else {
        graphics.drawText(judgeName, (int) (this.backgroundBitmap.getWidth() * 0.50) - (namePixelWidth/2), this.backgroundBitmap.getHeight() - font.getHeight() - 15);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly want to use a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern, defining something like

```
/**
 * Strategy to render some text, of two size variants, centered horizontally
 * at a specified position.
 */
public interface TextRenderer {
    public enum FontSize { LARGE, SMALL };
    public void render(String text, int x, int y, FontSize size);
}

/**
 * TextRenderer Factory that uses the ScreenDimension to determine sizes of LARGE
 * and SMALL fonts to use.
 */
public class ScreenDimensionAwareTextRendererFactory {
    public static TextRenderer getTextRenderer(Graphics gc) {
        Font baseFont = Font.getDefault();
        int fontWidth = ScreenDimension.getFontWidth();
        return fontWidth == 320
                ? new DefaultTextRenderer(gc, baseFont.derive(Font.PLAIN,10,Ui.UNITS_pt), baseFont.derive(Font.PLAIN,6,Ui.UNITS_pt))
                : new DefaultTextRenderer(gc, baseFont.derive(Font.PLAIN,12,Ui.UNITS_pt), baseFont.derive(Font.PLAIN,8,Ui.UNITS_pt));
    }
}

public class DefaultTextRenderer implements TextRenderer {
    protected Map<FontSize,Font> fontSizeMap = new HashMap<FontSize,Font>();
    protected Graphics gc;
    public DefaultTextRenderer(Graphics gc, Font largeFont, Font smallFont) {
        this.gc = gc;
        fontSizeMap.put(LARGE, largeFont);
        fontSizeMap.put(SMALL, smallFont);        
    }
    public void render(String text, int x, int y, FontSize size) {
        Font font = fontSizeMap.get(size)
        int pixelWidth = font.getAdvance(text);
        gc.setFont(font);

        // TODO: note here I'm not dealing with the vertical offsets you're using
        // which are dependent upon the font size. It would be possible, but
        // I suspect what you really ought to be doing is consistently rendering
        // text on a baseline.
        // The way you could adjust this to closer match what you appear to be doing
        // would be to have arguments to render() which indicate vertical alignment.
        // something like 
        // TextRenderer.VerticalAlignment = enum { BASELINE, TOP, BOTTOM }
        // and based on something like that you could compute here the y offset
        // based on the selected font.
        // I can't do that now because you're "magic numbers" hard coded don't explain
        // what they're trying to do
        gc.drawText(text, Math.round(x - (pixelWidth / 2)), y);
    }
}

// your example
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paint(graphics);

    String strScore = String.valueOf(score);
    TextRenderer textRenderer = ScreenDimensionAwareTextRendererFactory.getTextRenderer(graphics);
    int middleX = Math.round(this.backgroundBitmap.getWidth() / 2);
    textRenderer.render(strScore, middleX, 10, TextRenderer.TextSize.LARGE);
    textRenderer.render(judgeName, middleX, this.backgroundBitmap.getHeight(), TextRenderer.TextSize.SMALL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if the graphics reference is set within the calling class should the graphics reference not be passed into the LargeTextRenderer & SmallTextRenderer classes ?

Comment: Indeed, if the use case requires that the GC is provided to the strategy implementation then so be it. Likewise if you need to be able to provide locations on the GC, they get passed in too. Without more context in you initial code sample it's not possible to know this for the answer. I'll update the code

Comment: The key to remember here is that the Strategy pattern defines a consistent interface, in this case something like "render some text at some x/y position", and implementations define how that happens, specifically here the implementations differ in how they render different sized text. This is illustrated by the fact that the different implementations main differences are focused around the font width/size.

Comment: I've added another code snippet from a different method, could the same strategy pattern you described be used in this case ?

Comment: Yes, I'll update my answer to match the extended sample you've provided

Comment: After multiple edits I think it's there. Note that the doc for the interface TextRenderer really explains what it's there to do. If you have other classes which have other expectations, such as the text not being centered horizontally, then the interface would need to be expanded to suit, much like I explained about the vertical alignment. It may need some tweaking to compile, I've not tried, but you should be able to see the general idea, and it greatly simplifies the calling code, which is the benefit of this pattern.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll go through your code and try to implement it in the app, will take some time though, so if you don't mind I'll leave this question open, ill prob have a point or two I need clarifying when I go through it. Hopefully tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a delegate object that would inspect your 10 classes to draw the text appropriately.

You could also simply make a static helper function to execute that code (simple and easy way).

In fact it is hard to give a proper opinion without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

If the conditionals don't vary, you could use the Servant design pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_Servant